# I'm importing the fbx file in ue4. It's being imported in parts (leg, arm, head) how can I import it as a single piece?

Tags: import, export, unreal-engine4, fbx, unreal-engine5

I'm importing the fbx file in ue4. It's being imported in parts (leg, arm, head) how can I import it as a single piece?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nGca.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

All the components of the character need to be in a hierarchy in your FBX file, so that there is only one object at the top level.

Then you need to import it as a skeletal mesh.

[image: Skeletal Mesh Import]

If you leave 'Skeleton' and 'Physics Asset' as 'None' it will create the necessary objects for you.

See also: [How To Import Skeletal Meshes](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/WorkingWithContent/Importing/FBX/HowTo/ImportingSkeletalMeshes)